# JAX-RS register instance as an endpoint?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-1.0

I have a  rest endpoint class similar to this:

```
@Path("/users")
public class Users {
    private final Database database;

    public Users(Database database) {
        this.database = database;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    public Response Get(@PathParam("id") int id) {
        User user = this.database.get(id);
        return Response.ok(user).build();
    }
}
```

And a main method:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Database database = new SomeDBImplementation();
        Users users = new Users(database);
        
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create("http://localhost:8080");
        server.start();
    }
}
```

How do I make the server use the users instance as an endpoint? I'm using jersey-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a [`ResourceConfig`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.19.1/jersey/index.html?com/sun/jersey/api/core/ResourceConfig.html) instance and then pass it to the [`HttpServerFactory.create(uri, resourceConfig)`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.19.1/jersey/index.html?com/sun/jersey/api/container/httpserver/HttpServerFactory.html) method. There are different implementations of `ResourceConfig`. The most basic one is the [`DefaultResourceConfig`](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/1.19.1/jersey/index.html?com/sun/jersey/api/core/DefaultResourceConfig.html). To register a resource instance you would just do

```java
ResourceConfig config = new DefaultResourceConfig();
config.getRootResourceSingletons().add(users);
HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(uri, config);
```

Comment: That would make a lot of sense, although I'm getting "The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.". I'll set this as an answer once I find a solution

Comment: Seems like it's an unmodifiable collection. Apparently there are different versions of jersey-server, apparently I also need to use jetty or something, the whole thing is a mess

Comment: The only other guess I have is `getExplicitRootResources().put("users", users)`. It might help if you post all your dependencies. Maybe there is something else going on that is preventing registration.

Comment: If you're starting a new project (or just learning), I would suggest using Jersey 2.x or even 3.x instead.